# retry saving unique table until having a unique value in jpa

Tags: java, jpa

I have a database table looking like:

```
CREATE TABLE tag (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    last_modified_at timestamp without time zone,
    title text NOT NULL,
    slug text UNIQUE
);
```

Additionally I have an entity file, where I declare it for jpa:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag extends BaseEntity implements Slugged {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String title;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    private String slug;

    @Override
    public void slugify() {
        slug = new Slugify().slugify(title);
    }

}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void preSave() {
        if (this instanceof Slugged) {
            if ( StringUtils.isEmpty (((Slugged) this).getSlug()) ) {
                ((Slugged) this).slugify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the BaseEntity I am having a `PrePersist` where I set the slug, which needs to be unique. It basically works. But sometimes it might happen that the slug is the same for 2 tuples. In that case I want that the first one has the original slug and the next one gets slug and an increasing number next to it.

Example:

```
title     | slug
------------------------
a b       | ab
ab        | ab1
```

Since `a b` got created first it got the slug `ab` and the next entry with the same slug should get `ab1`

What is the best way to archieve this behaviour?

Comment: I suppose the database type is PostgreSQL.

Comment: yes it is a postgres database